# ...жмурил и хлопал глазами. Управление при однородных членах предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология, глаголы, управление

...жмурил и хлопал глазами – пример из Гоголя. И у других писателей встречается "наличие общего зависимого слова при различном управлении... [,которое] нарушает грамматико-стилистическую норму" (https://sci.house/russkiy-yazyik-scibook/205-upravlenie-pri-odnorodnyih-chlenah-37504.html). По правилу надо бы исправить: жмурил глаза и хлопал ими.

- Возникает вопрос: о каком нарушении нормы идет речь?
- Очевидно, что исправленный вариант уступает стилистически и художественно оригиналу. Употребление подобных сочетаний: жмурил и хлопал глазами – естественно для языка, так как является проявлением языковой экономии: смысл передается, но в такой форме, где грамматическая связь устанавливается с ближайшим словом (жмурил и **хлопал глазами**), чего вполне хватает для понимания всей фразы; а правильные грамматические связи делают фразу по восприятию избыточной, громоздкой (жмурил глаза и хлопал ими). Так, например, в таких случаях тоже действует языковая экономия: *Можно представить себе, каким громовым ударом разразилось это письмо **над моим отцом и матерью*** (Аксаков). Если восстанавливать правильные грамматические связи, то надо писать так: "над моим отцом и моей матерью", – ведь согласование "над моим матерью" является точно таким же нарушением стилистически-грамматической нормы, как об этом говорится в отношении управления при однородных членах. Так почему такое согласование при однородных членах (**над** **моим** отцом и **матерью**) в правилах не называется нарушением, а такое вот управление при однородных членах (**жмурил** и хлопал **глазами**) указывается как нарушение. И в первом, и во втором случае наблюдается действие языковой экономии. Почему-то во втором случае оно не осознано. Может, потому что глагол – самая сложная часть речи, имеющая самое большое количество сложных, разнообразных грамматических категорий.
- Может, надо перестать бояться подобных фраз "жмурил и хлопал глазами" и оставлять их? Что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: *По правилу надо бы исправить: жмурил глаза и хлопал ими.* — Вы считаете, что это лучший вариант исправления? Не лучше ли будет "... а только хлопал глазами и жмурился" (ну или в обратном порядке)?

Answer (score 3):

> Возникает вопрос: о каком нарушении нормы идет речь?

О нарушении вот этой нормы. По вашей же ссылке.

> При двух или нескольких управляющих словах общее зависимое слово
>   допустимо, когда каждое из управляющих слов требует того же падежа и
>   предлога, например: читать и конспектировать книгу; подбирать и
>   готовить кадры; протравливать и яровизировать семена; надеяться и
>   рассчитывать на помощь.

//

> Очевидно, что исправленный вариант уступает стилистически и
>   художественно оригиналу.

Да. Других "вопросов" в этом длинном абзаце не вижу.

> Может, надо перестать бояться подобных фраз "жмурил и хлопал глазами"
>   и оставлять их? Что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Категорически нет. Подобные фразы допустимы только в художественном тексте как выразительное средство для сознания иронического эффекта. У Гоголя - именно такой случай. Это своего рода эрратив - умышленное нарушение нормы. И здесь он смотрится вполне уместным.

Что касается двух других примеров из Розенталя, то не сомневаюсь, что и Тургенев, и Эренбург (на крайний случай - их редакторы) прекрасно понимали, что нарушают норму. И знали, для чего они это делают. Но вот результат уже не столь очевиден. Смотрится хуже, чем у Гоголя. Возможно, виной всему исторические изменения в самом восприятии подобных "вольностей".

Розенталь, кстати, и не утверждает, что подобные места надо неприменно править или, наоборот, кодифицировать. Он просто отмечает, что подобное нарушение может иметь место у известных авторов, но оценки тому не дает.

Answer (score 1):

**Возникает вопрос: о каком нарушении нормы идет речь?**

Норма, о нарушении которой идёт речь, описана в первом абзаце по Вашей ссылке.

**Может, надо перестать бояться подобных фраз "жмурил и хлопал глазами" и оставлять их? Что вы думаете по этому поводу?**

Я считаю, что страх здесь ни при чём, а нарушение правил русского языка не следует оправдывать экономией букв или неумением выразить ту же мысль красиво и грамотно — для этого не запрещено даже использовать другие слова и предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Я перестану бояться подобных фраз, когда словосочетание "жмурил глазами" (в современном русском языке - оставим Гоголя в покое, он тоже не безгрешен) перестанет вызывать у меня рвотные позывы.

- жмурил (что?) глаза (вариант - жмурился)
- шмыгал (чем?) носом
- хлопал (чем?) ушами
- надувал (что?) щеки (а не "надувал щеками")

---

Прочитал параграф по ссылке. Авторы там сами запутались. Пример из Тургенева - не к месту.